# Проблемы с логикой pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Есть следующий код

```
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > (left_line + (width / 2)) \
            and not keys[pygame.K_UP] and not keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        x -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < (right_line - (width * 2 - width / 2)) \
            and not keys[pygame.K_UP] and not keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        x += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > ((res_y - res_y) + 10):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            y -= speed + 6
            nitro = True
        else:
            y -= speed
            nitro = False
```

Проблема заключается в том , что когда нажаты одновременно клавиши K_UP, K_SPACE и K_RIGHT то срабатывает условие

```
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            y -= speed + 6
            nitro = True
```

Если нажата просто K_UP и K_SPACE , то условие тоже срабатывает как нужно

Но когда нажаты клавиши K_UP,K_SPACE и K_LEFT условие не срабатывает

Не могу понять из за чего

Даже если делаю вот так

```
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > ((res_y - res_y) + 10):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            y -= speed + 6
            nitro = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            y -= speed + 6
            nitro = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            y -= speed + 6
            nitro = True
        else:
            y -= speed
            nitro = False
```

Срабатывает все кроме условия с K_LEFT

Если вместо K_LEFT использовать любую другую клавишу , то все работает

Answer (score 0):

Вы пробовали сделать так?

```py
if keys[pygame.K_UP] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
    y -= speed + 6
    nitro = True
```

Comment: Не правильно изначально описал проблему , само условие с K_UP срабатывает , не срабатывает уже условие с K_SPACE

Comment: @SlaerWay Возможно сейчас мой ответ вам поможет

Comment: Даже если делаю так

    `if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > ((res_y - res_y) + 10):
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            y -= speed + 6
            nitro = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            y -= speed + 6
            nitro = True
        elif keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            y -= speed + 6
            nitro = True
        else:
            y -= speed
            nitro = False`

То работает все , кроме варианта с K_LEFT

Comment: Почему то не получается нормально вставить код

Comment: @SlaerWay Да, это комментарии, тут другой формат

Comment: К сожалению не помогло

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена , все было из за клавиатуры , которая почему то только с клавишей K_LEFT не может обработать больше двух нажатий одновременно